# SSH Timeout Error Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, ssh, openssh, dokku

I am trying to push a project to dokku master. I am simply using the dokku setup tutorial and when I get to this stage

```
git push dokku master
```

I am greeted with a message

```
ssh: connect to host dokku.me port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

So in my searching I saw that I should change my ssh config file to this

```
# GITHUB
Host github.com
   Hostname ssh.github.com
    Port 443
```

This still give the same error.

When I use the command

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get this message

```
warning: agent returned different signature type ssh-rsa (expected rsa-sha2-512)
Hi XXXX You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Any clue as to why I cannot connect to either port 22 or port 443? Its my local machine at home so neither port should be blocked

Comment: `connect to host dokku.me port 22: Connection timed out` dokku.me currently resolves to 10.0.0.2, which isn't routable over the Internet. Do you want to connect to dokku.me, or do you want to connect to github?

Comment: Just want to git push my app to dokku. The command i follwed was here http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/application-deployment/

Comment: At what host/IP do you run dokku server?

Comment: I run on digital ocean. I installed the dokku container in a droplet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dokku.me` hostname is an example hostname used within the Dokku docs to refer to your server. When setting your git remote, you should replace it with either the IP address of your server or an associated hostname. For example:

```sh
# dokku docs
git remote add dokku dokku@dokku.me:example-app

# should instead be the following if using a server ip
# replace 10.0.0.2 with your server's IP
git remote add dokku dokku@10.0.0.2:example-app

# or the following if you are using a hostname
git remote add dokku dokku@your-hostname.com:example-app
```